# Efficient way to extend a numpy array with values that do not already exist in that array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm very new to python/numpy. I want to store values in an numpy array, that are solutions of a simple combination problem. 
In this I have two given values x and y and a bound with x<=bound and y<=bound. I need to find all integer solutions a*x+b*y that satisfy a*x+b*y<=bound with "a" and "b" both positive integer. So I'm doing this by iterating over all feasible inputs for "a" and "b" and extend my array with the solutions.

The problem is, that I need a solution only to appear once. Like in my code example below, for x=3, y=5 and bound=20, the solution 15 would be a result of a*3+b*5 for (a,b)=(5,0) and also for (a,b)=(0,3). I do not need the redundance. The best way I came up with until now, is to check in an if-block, if the computed solution is not already stored, and only if so, that value is added to my array.

Is there a more efficient way to do this, other than checking the entire existing array in every single iteration step? Like a function other than np.append which automatically only stores values, that do not already exist?
Or is there a way to first store all computed solutions, but then return only an array with none-redundant values? (And would that be mor efficient?)

PS: I'm working with very large bounds and my array needs to store a few thousands of values.

```
import numpy as np


x=3
y=5
bound=20


arr=([]) # empty array at first

for a in range(np.int(bound/x)+1):
    for b in range(np.int((bound-a*x)/y)+1):
        feasible_combination=a*x+b*y

        if feasible_combination not in arr[:]:  # no need for redundance 
            arr=np.append(arr,feasible_combination)
arr=np.sort(arr)
print(arr)
```

Comment: It's faster collect arrays in a list.  Or for unique values consider a `set`.

Answer (score 0):

Here two faster versions, one using a `set` and the other doing almost all the work in NumPy:

```
def combinations_set(x, y, bound):
    combs = set()
    for a in range(np.int(bound/x)+1):
        for b in range(np.int((bound-a*x)/y)+1):
            combs.add(a*x+b*y)
    return np.sort(list(combs))

def combinations_ix(x, y, bound):
    a, b = np.ix_(*[np.arange(int(bound/_)+1) for _ in (x, y)])
    combs = a*x + b*y
    return np.sort(np.unique(combs[combs <= bound]))
```

For the following sample, `combinations_ix` gives a 1607-fold speedup on my machine compared to the original code, but `combinations_set` is pretty competitive (and should use less memory than `combinations_ix`):

```
In [58]: %timeit combinations(200, 234, 100000)   # original code as function
1 loops, best of 3: 8.23 s per loop

In [59]: %timeit combinations_set(200, 234, 100000)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.1 ms per loop

In [60]: %timeit combinations_ix(200, 234, 100000)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.12 ms per loop
```